# Automatic git pull on server

Tags: github, server, game-development, ngrok, fivem

So I have a server where I keep development files used for my game server. With multiple developers, I was wondering if there is a way to have the repository located on that server automatically pull new files as my developers push their commits to the online master? I have looked into ngrok but am unable to figure out how to implement this as this is not a web server and the files are not located on the root drive of the computer. Hope someone can give me a good step by step or point me in the right direction of a tutorial!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux you can use crontab, on windows you can use Windows Task Scheduler